# Flutter - Set Image as a background for Material

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a `return Material` with an Image as a background.

This is my code:

```
    return Material(
        //I tried add this code 
        child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: AssetImage('assets/img1.png'))
        ),
          color: Colors.white,
        //======================
    child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
              ....
              text("Some text");)
      ]
    )
```

How can I set background for `return Material`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a container  and show the image in Decoration

```
 Material(
    //I tried add this code
    child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        image: AssetImage('assets/img1.png'))),
    color: Colors.white,
    ))
```

Comment: I tried but `The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified`.